# Elixir Phoenix: Using `for` and `as` on a login form element using new heex syntax?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Versions:

- Elixir 1.14.4
- Phoenix 1.7.2

Noob here on both Elixir and Phoenix. I am really struggling to learn that framework.

I am trying to go through a user authentication [tutorial](https://elixircasts.io/user-authentication-with-phoenix) with a newer version of phoenix. The tutorial suggests to implement a login user form of (the source can be found in [Github](https://github.com/elixircastsio/042-user-authentication/blob/8cd88fb3b087434a4c13f95cb0decc9e9d7f0e8f/lib/teacher_web/templates/session/new.html.eex)):

```
<h1>Sign in</h1>
<%= form_for @conn, session_path(@conn, :new), [as: :session], fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :username, placeholder: "username" %>
  <%= password_input f, :password, placeholder: "password" %>
  <%= submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

As I struggled using the `<%= form_for` syntax (not working), I am trying to use something like below which I copy-pasted from the auto-generated `user_html/user_form.html.heex` (my sample uses a little different `name` attribute):

```
<.simple_form :let={f} for={???} action={~p"/login"}>
  <.input field={f[:name]} type="text" label="Username" />
  <.input field={f[:password]} type="password" label="Password" />
  <:actions>
    <.button>Sign In</.button>
  </:actions>
</.simple_form>
```

In the auto-generated `components/core_components.ex` I can see `simple_form` implemented with a `.form`-tag. However, I have no idea how to use the `for` (is that `@conn`?) and `as` (in the original code `[as: :session]`) attributes to the form.

My "project" is pretty much `mix phx.new project` plus the tutorial.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement the code to the new form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still confused a lot. But here is that login form working. As mentioned in the question there are some changes to the original tutorial.

The original login form

```
<%= form_for @conn, session_path(@conn, :new), [as: :session], fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :username, placeholder: "username" %>
  <%= password_input f, :password, placeholder: "password" %>
  <%= submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

changed to:

```
<.simple_form :let={f} for={@changeset} as={:session} method={"post"}  action={~p"/login"}>
  <.input field={f[:name]} type="text" label="Username" />
  <.input field={f[:password]} type="password" label="Password" />
  <:actions>
    <.button>Sign In</.button>
  </:actions>
</.simple_form>
```

I guess, since I pass back a changeset that contains the `name` and then retry the log in, submitting makes the system look for a `PUT` path, which I don't provide. Hence, I added the `method={"post"}`. Is this the right way to do it? I'm not so sure.

Below is the original `SessionController` from the tutorial (a little shortened)

```
defmodule TeacherWeb.SessionController do
  #... 

  def new(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "new.html")
  end

  def create(conn, %{"session" => auth_params}) do
    user = Accounts.get_by_username(auth_params["username"])
    case Comeonin.Bcrypt.check_pass(user, auth_params["password"]) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_session(:current_user_id, user.id)
      |> put_flash(:info, "Signed in successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: movie_path(conn, :index))
    {:error, _} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "There was a problem with your username/password")
      |> render("new.html")
    end
  end

  def delete(conn, _params) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

I guess the `changeset` is now mandatory in the form. So, I added that:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Accounts.change_user(%User{})
    render(conn, :new, changeset: changeset)
  end
```

and

```
def create(conn, %{"session" => auth_params}) do
  user = Accounts.get_by_name(auth_params["name"])
  { res_creds, user } = if user do
    { Comeonin.Bcrypt.check_pass(user, auth_params["password"]), user }
  else
    { {:error, "User does not exist"}, %User{} }
  end
  case res_creds do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_session(:current_user_id, user.id)
      |> put_flash(:info, "Signed in successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: ~p"/")
    {:error, _} ->
      cs = User.invalidate_password(user) # This is just to create dummy changeset, so that the form works
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "There was a problem with your username/password")
      |> render("new.html", changeset: cs)
  end
end
```

It feels like the new version works quite a bit differently which is somewhat troublesome (unless I handled it not in the right way). But for now I'm happy that that works.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `for` is the changeset, perhaps try the `phx.gen.html` generator to see some example code for how that all ties together.